# Generalized linear model vs Generalized additive model

Tags: r, glm, gam

I'm trying to follow this paper: [Using a data science approach to predict cocaine use frequency from depressive symptoms](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0376871618308093?token=F1D7B5119F5F6CBEAD3B72FDA079B382E2ADF252486606A4C87EDB2A33BFE3375535798CC267B7BF75247564C66EA5F3) where they use glm, gam with the beck inventory depression. So I did found a similiar dataset to test those models. However I'm having a hard time with both models. For example I have two variables d64a and d64b, and they're coded with 1,2,3,4 meaning that they're ordinal. Also, in the paper y2 is only the value of 1 but i have also a variable extra (that can be dependent, the proportion of consume)

For the GAM model I have:

```
b<-gam(y2~s(d64a)+s(d64b),data=DATOS2)
```

but I have the following error:

```
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom
```

Meanwhile for the glm, I have the following:

```
d<-glm(y2~d64a+d64b,data=DATOS2)
```

I don't know since d64a and d64b are ordinal I have to use factor()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that one or both of `d64a` and `d64b` do not have **9** (nine) unique values.

By default `s(...)` will create a basis with nine functions. You get this error if there are fewer than nine unique values in the covariate.

Check which covariates are affected using:

```
length(unique(d64a))
length(unique(d64b))
```

and see what the number of unique values is for each of the covariates you wish to include. Then set the `k` argument to the number returned above if it is less than nine. FOr example, assume that the above checks returned `5` and `7` unique covariates, then you would indicate this by setting `k` as follows:

```
b <- gam(y2 ~ s(d64a, k = 5) + s(d64b, k = 7), data = DATOS2)
```